# skinning scroller flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, skinning, spark-skinning

I need to skin the scrollbar. I have figured out how to change base color, however need to change the border color of scrollbar as well (I need it more greyish).

Here's the code:

```
<s:WindowedApplication name="scrollerSkinning"
           xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           width="1024" height="780">

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    s|Scroller {
    verticalScrollPolicy: on;
    }

    s|VScrollBar {
    chromeColor: #FFFFFF;           
    }

</fx:Style>

<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:Image id="imageGeneralPage" source="@Embed('images/genpage.png')"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Image genpage.png is greater in size than the application window, thus there shows up vertical scrollbar which I need to skin a lil bit, nothing fancy, only color change.
Appreciate any hint, thnx

Comment: I guess I'm not sure you want to change.  A screenshot may help here.  Do scrollbars have a visual borders?  Perhaps you want to style the track or thumb?

Comment: yea wanted to add image, but since I've just registered it said need more rating to do so. Anyhow made image and here's the link:
http://postimage.org/image/hyu2la2f5/

Comment: I think you may have to set skins on the skin parts of the VScrollbar directly.

Comment: I think @www.Flextras.com is probably right. Read this answer if you don't know how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897386/mxml-spark-skin-a-vgroups-scrollbar/10897705#10897705

Comment: thnx alot RIAstar, that's what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

thnx both of you for replies.
first I did as RIAstar suggested here:
[MXML: Spark skin a VGroups scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897386/mxml-spark-skin-a-vgroups-scrollbar/10897705#10897705)

then copied the default skins:

```
<s:Button id="track" top="16" bottom="15" height="54"
          focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
          skinClass="mySkins.VScrollBarTrackSkin1" />
```

in "mySkin" package and edited the rectangle SolidColorStroke color property:

```
<s:Rect top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" minWidth="14" minHeight="14">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x888888" weight="1"/>
    </s:stroke>
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0xCACACA" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Thnx alot for help.

P.S. @RIAstar, don't know how to give you kudos, tho :(